# Jenkins plugin checkbox: GUI value differs from config.xml

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm making a change to a Jenkins plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Stash+pullrequest+builder+plugin), as I would like to add a couple of options to it.

However, having added two new checkboxes to the `config.jelly`, they don't appear to work correctly in the job config through the GUI.

`config.jelly`:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
  ...
  <f:advanced>
  ...
    <f:entry title="Report build started to Stash?" field="reportBuildStartedToStash">
      <f:checkbox default="true"/>
    </f:entry>
    <f:entry title="Report build result to Stash?" field="reportBuildStatusToStash">
      <f:checkbox default="true"/>
  </f:advanced>
</j:jelly>
```

If I add this plugin to a job like so:[image]

Then the two checkboxes default to "true" as expected. This is reflected in the config.xml:

```
  <triggers>
    <stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashBuildTrigger plugin="stash-pullrequest-builder@1.3.1-SNAPSHOT">
      ...
      <reportBuildStartedToStash>true</reportBuildStartedToStash>
      <reportBuildStatusToStash>true</reportBuildStatusToStash>
    </stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashBuildTrigger>
  </triggers>
```

However, if I untick these checkboxes, save the changes, and reload the Job Configuration page, the checkboxes will appear to be ticked again.

Could this be a problem with my .jelly config? I can't understand how or why.

For reference, my branch is here: https://github.com/blaffoy/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/tree/optional-messages-to-stash

This issue appears to be same as raised [here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Issues-with-boolean-parameter-in-config-jelly-td3703052.html), but the solution suggested doesn't fix the problem for me. That is, to replace `<f:checkbox default="true"/>` with `<f:checkbox/>`

Comment: Do you have your latest code checked in a branch somewhere? I don't see the additional fields in config.jelly and I'm curious what your constructor looks like in StashBuildTrigger.java

Comment: Hi Chris, the config.jelly is here: https://github.com/blaffoy/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/blob/optional-messages-to-stash/src/main/resources/stashpullrequestbuilder/stashpullrequestbuilder/StashBuildTrigger/config.jelly, and the relevant Java class is here: https://github.com/blaffoy/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/blob/optional-messages-to-stash/src/main/java/stashpullrequestbuilder/stashpullrequestbuilder/StashBuildTrigger.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work by prefixing the getter methods in `StashBuildTrigger.java` with "is" e.g.

```java
public boolean isReportBuildStartedToStash() 
public boolean isDeleteBuildStartedToStash()
public boolean isReportBuildStatusToStash()
```

I think this would also work with a "get" prefix but I havent tested it. As per the [jenkins plugin doc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins):

> Define getters for the configuration fields, or make the fields
>   "public final". This allows Jelly script to read the values to
>   populate the configuration page.
>
> A few things to notice: the 'get' was automatically stripped from the
>   method name, and the first letter of the remaining method name was
>   lower-cased. I'd recommend using the Java convention for naming
>   methods (e.g. starting getters with 'get' and using CamelCase) so that
>   Jelly can always find the methods.

Example [java naming conventions](https://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/method.html):

> Use the prefixes get and set for getter and setter methods. ... If the
>   method returns a boolean value, use is or has as the prefix for the
>   method name.